# Heroku log - error H10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just pushed a new version of my code. Something has gone wrong and I have a H10 error from heroku. I don't understand what these logs mean. Can anyone help me to identify what's gone wrong. Thank you.

```
$ heroku logs
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521397+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521398+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521405+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521408+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521350+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521403+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521406+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521412+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521416+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521422+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521414+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521418+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521426+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521432+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521356+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521434+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521358+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521430+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521351+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521438+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521360+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521364+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521381+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521376+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-10-11T00:50:40.521383+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-10-11T00:50:41.462327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-10-11T00:50:41.474502+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-10-11T01:32:24.352226+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.coalfacer.com request_id=e1757461-c607-4fa2-bb1d-415f09cbe307 fwd="66.249.67.9" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-10-11T01:37:27.154896+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-10-11T01:37:35.017370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 12098 -e production`
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618737+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:69:in `each_key'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618758+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:69:in `assert_valid_keys'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618896+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/project.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619164+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619315+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619501+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619730+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619852+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.614719+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618799+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:42:in `build'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619107+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619353+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619541+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619909+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618779+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:59:in `validate_options'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618915+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619201+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619334+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619522+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619748+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619871+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618471+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618859+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1401:in `belongs_to'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618993+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619050+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:207:in `require_dependency'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619182+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619296+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619473+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619711+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619833+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618706+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb:70:in `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: through (ArgumentError)
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618934+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619031+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:289:in `depend_on'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619126+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619239+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619371+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619654+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619890+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618878+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/project.rb:7:in `<class:Project>'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619012+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:330:in `require_or_load'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619088+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619220+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619428+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619692+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619813+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619447+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619635+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.614715+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:12098
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619277+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619560+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619579+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619597+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619947+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.614717+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618820+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/associations/builder/belongs_to.rb:16:in `build'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618973+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619069+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619145+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619258+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619390+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619674+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619794+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619928+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.614681+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-10-11T01:37:40.618839+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:12:in `build'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619409+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
2014-10-11T01:37:40.619617+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-10-11T01:37:41.593299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-10-11T01:37:41.601919+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: Could start here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed

Comment: thanks Will. I did start there - unfortunately the devcenter doesn't give any help for error code 10. The help starts for 11. I will email heroku separately.